# Python_Get url as input in python

Tags: python

I tried to get url as an input for my python program not working

```
import request 

get_url=raw_input(" ") 

Page = get.request('get_url')
```

But

```
Page = get.request('www.armagsolutions.com')
```

is working.
Can someone help me with a example to get url as input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
Page = get.request('get_url')
```

you pass as arg to function str *'get_url'* instead of variable `get_url`. Use instead

```
Page = get.request(get_url)
```

Comment: @magic if my answer solves your problem you could check it as right answer)

Comment: i want to give xpath or css seletor as input

`xpath_first = raw_input("> ")`

`services = tree.xpath(xpath_first)`

when i used like this .not working

i want to give xpath or css selector as an input 

can anyone explain with example @kvorobiev

Comment: @magic It would be better if you create a separate question with an code , example input and desired output